# How to save records in MYSQL db with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in UTC format and NOT LOCALTIME?

Tags: mysql, datetime, xampp, utc

Save records with column as 'created_date' which has CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which should be UTC time and not local time

Answer (score 2):

**UTC_TIMESTAMP() function**

In MySQL, the `UTC_TIMESTAMP` returns the current UTC date and time as a value in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format depending on the usage of the function i.e. in a string or numeric context.

**Note :** Since `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` works on current datetime, your output may vary from the output shown.

**Syntax:** `UTC_TIMESTAMP; UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

**Code:** `SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMESTAMP();`

**Sample Output:**

```
 mysql> SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP,UTC_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+---------------------+
| UTC_TIMESTAMP       | UTC_TIMESTAMP()     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2015-04-14 22:52:11 | 2015-04-14 22:52:11 | 
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. @Nehorai.

Comment: created_at column has timestamp datatype and by default it is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which will fetch the current time of system. 
The data is coming from API  in UTC format and created_at will be in local time. This is my issue. Please suggest.

Comment: Solution : API wil send the created date time which I will set in the created_at field directly. SO no need of system generated CURRENT_TIMESTAMP . Please suggest! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is with a trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_to_utc` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set new.my_field=utc_timestamp();
END//
DELIMITER ;
```